# JPA Predicate ManyToMany with Map

Tags: java, jpa

I am not very familiar with Predicates in java, and have tried to google around to find a solution to my problem, so any helps/hints are welcome.

So here it is:

In my entity model I have the following mapping

```
public class Entity{
    @ManyToMany
    @MapKeyEnumerated(STRING)
    private Map<A, B> partners = new HashMap<A, B>();
}
```

How do I go around to make a Predicate that gives me a result with all entities that has partners.B.id = 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **joins** when building your predicates.

For your example, it can look like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<entity> root = cq.from(Entity.class);
MapJoin<Entity, A, B> mapJoin = root.joinMap("partners");

Predicate predicate = cb.equal(mapJoin.get("id"), 2);

em.createQuery(cq.select(root).distinct(true).where(predicate));
```

(Remark: I did not test this code)